# Not getting proper waypoints GoogleMap Api

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mkmapview

i want to draw polyline using googleMap Api on MKMapView.
i am doing this way. Here is Code for it.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

NSString *urlString =@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json";

NSString *origin = @"23.0061,72.5647";
NSString *dstinatin = @"23.03293,72.6284";


MKPointAnnotation *annotationEnd = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
[annotationEnd setCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.0293, 72.6284)];
[annotationEnd setTitle:@"Ending"]; //You can set the subtitle too
[self.mkMapView addAnnotation:annotationEnd];


NSDictionary *dictParameters = @{@"origin" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",origin], @"destination" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dstinatin], @"mode" : @"driving", @"sensor" : @"true"};

[manager GET:urlString parameters:dictParameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSArray *routesArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"routes"];
     if ([routesArray count] > 0)
      {
        NSDictionary *routeDict = [routesArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSDictionary *routeOverviewPolyline = [routeDict objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
        NSString *points = [routeOverviewPolyline objectForKey:@"points"];
        MKPolyline *line = [self polylineWithEncodedString:points];

        [mkMapView addOverlay:line];
      }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

my decoding method is :

```
-(MKPolyline *)polylineWithEncodedString:(NSString *)encodedString
{
const char *bytes = [encodedString UTF8String];
NSUInteger length = [encodedString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSUInteger idx = 0;

NSUInteger count = length / 4;
CLLocationCoordinate2D *coords = calloc(count, sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
NSUInteger coordIdx = 0;

float latitude = 0;
float longitude = 0;
while (idx < length) {
    char byte = 0;
    int res = 0;
    char shift = 0;

    do {
        byte = bytes[idx++] - 63;
        res |= (byte & 0x1F) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (byte >= 0x20);

    float deltaLat = ((res & 1) ? ~(res >> 1) : (res >> 1));
    latitude += deltaLat;

    shift = 0;
    res = 0;

    do {
        byte = bytes[idx++] - 0x3F;
        res |= (byte & 0x1F) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (byte >= 0x20);

    float deltaLon = ((res & 1) ? ~(res >> 1) : (res >> 1));
    longitude += deltaLon;

    float finalLat = latitude * 1E-5;
    float finalLon = longitude * 1E-5;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(finalLat, finalLon);
    coords[coordIdx++] = coord;

    if (coordIdx == count) {
        NSUInteger newCount = count + 10;
        coords = realloc(coords, newCount * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
        count = newCount;
    }
}

MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:coordIdx];
free(coords);

return polyline;
}
```

i think my coding is ok but i am not getting proper polyline. i am getting it as seen in screen shot. polyline's last end should be on my MKPointAnnotation. Sorry for my english. please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The destination of the route:

```
  23.03293,72.6284
//____^
```

isn't equal to the marker-position:

```
23.0293,72.6284
```

Comment: oops..  sorry sometimes some small things we can't figure out. thanks